# MySQL Rank in the Case of Ties

Tags: mysql, select, rank

I need some help dealing with ties when ranking in MySQL. For example:

PLAYER |  POINTS

- Mary:     90
- Bob:     90
- Jim:      65
- Kevin:    12

Bob and Mary should both be ranked #1. Jim should be #3. Kevin should be #4.

MySQL:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank +1 as rank, player, points FROM my_table
```

How can I change the SELECT statement so that the ranking is correct in the case of ties?

My real life problem is more complicated, but if I understand how to solve the above, then I should be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming name is unique

```
SELECT t1.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 t2 WHERE t2.score > t1.score) +1
AS rnk
FROM table_1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the message. As I understand it, the t2 is an alias for table_1? Did I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT players.*, COUNT(higher_ranking.id) + 1 AS rank
    FROM players
    LEFT JOIN players AS higher_ranking
        ON higher_ranking.points > players.points
    GROUP BY players.id
```

On Postgres, you could use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/tutorial-window.html) RANK() to achieve this, which is much nicer. I don't know of anything like that for MySQL.

Comment: Are you sure about your query? It returns me "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)"

Comment: I benchmarked both queries, a1ex07's query is faster. I did expect a JOIN to work better here... I'm not sure why its faster with a subquery.